# How can I make an extremely basic php captcha

Tags: php, random, numbers, captcha

So, I am basically making a website with a forgot password page. I want to add a captcha system. Now, I don't want anything that can't be made in like 5 minutes, just keep it short and simple. I want to have a verification for my form. What I want is a random number that is generated and displayed without an image. So, how do I do it? I've tried making a captcha system before, but the random number changes whenever I submit the stuff in the form.

Comment: Please show us [what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: You can try this: http://captchas.net/sample/php/ .

Answer (score 2):

You can make the user do a simple addition problem. It will prevent *most* automated submissions.

The basics of it would be like this:

```
$a = rand(1,10);
$b = rand(1,10);
$c = $a + $b; //throw this into a session var and check submission against it
echo "<p>$a + $b = <input type='text'/></p>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Super simple answer:

1. When loading the form page, create a session (`session_start()`)
2. Generate a random number and save it to a session variable: `$_SESSION['captcha']=[random_number]`
3. Create an image based on the session string (you'll need `GD` or similar library). Just have it create an image and print a text string on it based on the value of `$_SESSION['captcha']`. If you want to get fancy, try switching up fonts, colors, and rotate letters. *Remember, session variables are stored in temporary files (or DBs) on the server, so they're available on every file that includes the session)*
4. Have a captcha field for the user to fill out `<input type='text' name='captcha_field' />`
5. On submit, compare the `$_POST['captcha_field'] to $_SESSION['captcha']`. If they're the same, then proceed, otherwise force them to re-fill in the captcha field.

Comment: `$_SESSION['captcha']` will need to be a array, because if user opens multiple pages and submits any of the previous pages (not the last page) it will be invalid. I've tried this with tokens and it would only accept the last page opened since it replaces old values and creating a array I fixed my problem.

Comment: @Class -  not a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

You can store your random number in the session vars - i.e. `$_SESSION['captcha_code']` and check against this value.
This value is user specific and don't change over multiple requests. See [Session Handling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) for more information.